# New build configuration generates runtime error: could not load System.Runtime

Tags: c#, build, configuration, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I have a Solution with a .Net Framework 4.5.2 console application that depends on a .NetStandard 1.1 library.  The console applcation and library both compile and run perfectly.

My problems began when I created a new build confiuration, which I called "LocalDebug" and copied from the "Debug" configuration.   With the new configuration, it builds OK, but when I run it, it crashes the moment I access an object from the class library with this exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried closing visual studio, deleting all the intermediate folders and the .vs folder and re-compiling, but no luck.  I tried to add System.Runtime a reference in the console app, but it is not even presented as an option.   This shouldn't be failing anyway because I copied the configuration from "Debug", which works just fine.  What the heck???

Comment: Did you check to see what Framework the project is targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out what went wrong.  Eventually the debug build stopped compiling as well, so I Nuked The Site From Orbit, re-creating each project and adding in the code files, making sure it built at each step. As best as I can tell, I think my problems started with I mis-applied a nugget package to the wrong project.